# How to get rid of a circular service reference?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

I've seen a number of similar questions, but none gets the error in the same way, so I'll post it.

I created a new Windows Service in Visual Studio 2015, x64.  When I finished coding/testing it I added the service installer.  Every time I try to install the service from the command line it succeeds but fails to start.

I install the service with:

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe VerifyVideoFiles.exe
```

This gives:

```
Running a transacted installation.

Beginning the Install phase of the installation.
See the contents of the log file for the C:\TFS\Apps\...\VerifyVideoFiles.exe assembly's progress.
The file is located at C:\TFS\Apps\...\VerifyVideoFiles.InstallLog.

The Install phase completed successfully, and the Commit phase is beginning.
See the contents of the log file for the C:\TFS\Apps\...\VerifyVideoFiles.exe assembly's progress.
The file is located at C:\TFS\Apps\...\VerifyVideoFiles.InstallLog.

The Commit phase completed successfully.

The transacted install has completed.
```

Once I try to manually start it I get:

[image]

I created a simple method to spit out all of the dependencies, but didn't see any circular references:

```
    private static HashSet<string> ReferencedAssemblies = new HashSet<string>();

    ...
    OutputDependencies(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Program)), 0);
    ...

    static void OutputDependencies(Assembly assembly, int indent)
    {
        if (assembly == null) return;

        Console.WriteLine(new String(' ', indent * 4) + assembly.FullName);
        if (!ReferencedAssemblies.Contains(assembly.FullName))
        {
            ReferencedAssemblies.Add(assembly.FullName);

            foreach (var childAssembly in assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies())
            {
                OutputDependencies(Assembly.Load(childAssembly.FullName), indent + 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

This output the list of DLLs used:

```
VerifyVideoFiles, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
    mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
    System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
        mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
        System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
            mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
            System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
            System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
                mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
                System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
                System.Data.SqlXml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
                    mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Cultur'VerifyVideoFiles.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: VerifyVideoFiles.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.SqlXml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.SqlXml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
                    System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
                    System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
                System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
            System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
                mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
                System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
                System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
            System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
                mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
                System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
                System.Xml
                System.Numerics, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
                    mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
                System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
        System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
    System.Configuration.Install, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
        mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
        System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
        System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
        System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
            mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
            System.Xml
            System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
            System.ServiceModel.Internals, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
                mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
                System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
                System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
            SMDiagnostics, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
                mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
                System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
                System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
                System.ServiceModel.Internals, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
                System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
            System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
        System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
            mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
            System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
                mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
                System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
                System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
            System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
            System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
            System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
            System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
            System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
            Accessibility, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
                mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
            System.Deployment, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
                mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
                System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
                System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
                System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
                System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
                System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
                System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
            System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
                mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
                System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
    System.ServiceProcess, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
        mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
        System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
        System.Configuration.Install, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
        System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
        System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
    System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
    ScannerCode, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
        mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
        System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
        System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
        System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

Fed up with this project I started another.  Once again I get the same error.  Same list of DLLs.

Tried breaking the scanning code out to a library, using that from the Windows Service project.  Same issue.

I also have no other services that this code depends on:

[image]

I ran the sc.exe command at the console and it shows no service dependencies:

```
C:\...\x64\Release>sc qc VerifyVideoFiles
[SC] QueryServiceConfig SUCCESS

SERVICE_NAME: VerifyVideoFiles
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
        START_TYPE         : 2   AUTO_START
        ERROR_CONTROL      : 1   NORMAL
        BINARY_PATH_NAME   : "C:\TFS\Apps\...\VerifyVideoFiles.exe"
        LOAD_ORDER_GROUP   :
        TAG                : 0
        DISPLAY_NAME       : VerifyVideoFiles
        DEPENDENCIES       :
        SERVICE_START_NAME : \Ed
```

I just created an empty Windows Service and installed it.  Same error.  Maybe something Wonky with VS2015's installer template?

Any idea?  Any additional info I can supply?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not caused by a dll reference issue, but rather an installation error. Look at MSDN docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms833802.aspx.

Comment: Yeah, saw that.  But it doesn't show where the circular reference is.  :s  The install logs show no issues.  I have no declared service dependencies for this service, it's just a simple folder parser.  Any idea how to tell what other services are being referenced?

Comment: Not sure if the error message is completely accurate. All reports online point to a corrupted/incomplete installation as a potential cause. Have you run the install/uninstall many times with not all instances completing successfully? Have you used EventViewer to see if the system is logging anything useful?

Comment: Yep, uninstalled and reinstalled a few million times.  All of them succeeded.  Event Viewer showed no useful information (as usual).  Tried rebooting.  Same issues with either Windows Service created.

Comment: rookie suggestion, but have you tried a reboot?

Comment: Yep.  And verified the registry had no references to anything even close tp "VerifyVideoFiles." :s

Comment: It *might* be a problem with Windows on your machine, rather than a problem with your service.  Do you have access to any other machines you could try it on - or perhaps you could install a virtual machine for testing?  Process Monitor might give you some useful information, if you use it to see what actually happens when you try to start the service.

Comment: I had been so busy trying to find the cause of the error I didn't try it on the destination machine.  Works fine there.  It's running 2012 R2, my dev machine is Windows 10.

Comment: Hmmm.  If you change the service name, does it then work on the dev machine?